# android 4.0 and above,Canvas.clipRect() ,memory leaks

Tags: android

is there any one has been met ? can someone give me a hit how to deal it? thanks a lot.

in my game, I used a large number of functions of Canvas.clipRect(),I found that,in android 4.0 and above,after the game ran for 10 mins, its process killed by activityManager. And I gave up using Canvas.clipRect(), it ran properly for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Canvas.clipRect() try to use Canvas.clipRegion(). It works for me.

Sample workaround:

```
public void setClipNoOOM(int left, int top, int right, int bottom, Region.Op op, android.graphics.Canvas canvas) {
    if (op == Region.Op.INTERSECT)
        canvas.clipRect(left, top, right, bottom, op);
    else {
        RectF rectF = new RectF(left, top, right, bottom);
        Matrix m = canvas.getMatrix();
        m.mapRect(rectF);
        Region region = new Region((int)rectF.left, (int)rectF.top, (int)rectF.right, (int)rectF.bottom);
        canvas.clipRegion(region, op);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should avoid allocations during your drawing - if there isn't an intersect you're creating 2 objects (which will need to be GCed) everytime you call this method. I'm guessing you're calling this multiple times per frame, so you could easily be creating thousands of objects per second. Instead allocate a field for each and then use the `set()` methods inside this method.